# Container exited with code 0, and my app is served from the host OS

Tags: docker

I want to dockerize a Next.js project.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04

I first created a Next.js app in my `/home/user/project/` folder using `npx create-next-app`
So I have the project source code in my host machine.
But I want to dockerize it, so I created a `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
next:
    build:
        context: ./next
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: next
    volumes:
        - ./next:/var/www/html
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    networks:
        - nginx
```

And this is the `Dockerfile`:

```
#Creates a layer from node:alpine image.
FROM node:alpine

#Creates directories
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

#Sets an environment variable
ENV PORT 3000

#Sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY, and ADD commands
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

#Copy new files or directories into the filesystem of the container
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app

#Execute commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results
RUN npm install

##Copy new files or directories into the filesystem of the container
COPY . /usr/src/app

#Execute commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results
RUN npm run build

#Informs container runtime that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime
EXPOSE 3000

#Allows you to configure a container that will run as an executable
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
```

Then I build my container using `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`.
The container is built, but it's not running and is displaying `EXITED (0)`

and the LOGS has the following message:

```
Lifecycle scripts included in next-frontend@0.1.0:

  start

    next start


available via `npm run-script`:

  dev

    next dev

  build

    next build

  lint

    next lint
```

But of course if I run in the host `npm run dev`  it will run the app from the host, and not from the container (It runs, but that's not what I want)

I feel like there is some very fundamental mistake in my deployment, but I just started with Docker so I can't find out what

Also, I copied the `Dockerfile` from a tutorial so it might not fit the way I created the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]`... What?

From [`npm run`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script) documentation,

> This runs an arbitrary command from a package's `"scripts"` object. If no `"command"` is provided, it will list the available scripts.

In the `docker-compose.yml`, you need to override the `CMD` instruction (that is empty in your case) with the `npm` script you want to run. Something like this:

```
next:
    build:
        context: ./next
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: next
    command: ["start"]
    volumes:
        - ./next:/var/www/html
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    networks:
        - nginx
```

Since you are using the Compose Spec, this is the [reference](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#command) for the `command` instruction.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. But now I am confused, because in order to run my `Next.js` project on Windows, without Docker, I simply used to run `npm run dev` or `npm run build` or `npm run watch`, and these keywords were not defined in the `package.json`  scripts object - so how come I never used `npm start` there and in Docker I have to? Hope you understand my confusion

Comment: Not an expert on Node but, as far as I know, a script has to be declared in `package.json`. It is definitely weird that you do not have them but the application starts anyway. Maybe the framework you are using inject them in some other ways but I have no idea how (honestly, I am not sure it is even possible, we are probably missing something).

Comment: Thank you, so you have any idea what was he trying to achieve with `ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]`? Maybe he meant `ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]`? Also, how does that `command: ["start"]` knows it's `npm start` and not just `start`?

Comment: You are welcome :) `ENTRYPOINT` is the fixed part that you want to run, `COMMAND` is the variable one. `npm run` could always be executed before an `npm` command, so it is a good idea to keep it fixed. Instead, the `COMMAND` statement in docker can be changed when starting the container, even if specified it can be easily overridden with a `docker run your_image custom_command`, where `custom_command` could be `start`, `build`, `test` etc.

Comment: (I'd suggest setting `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]` in the Dockerfile, not setting `ENTRYPOINT`, and not overriding `command:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  This is a little clearer, and if you need something like a debugging shell, you can 'docker-compose run next sh` without more complex options.)

Comment: Thank you all. @DavidMaze, if I replace it with `CMD` and not overriding `command`, how can I run the `npm start` of the container, rather the `npm start` of the host? Because it will start the project on my host instead of on the container (The host also had `npm` installed, and the source code is in the host),
@MarcoLuzzara I'm afraid I still didn't understand the meaning of `ENTRYPOINT`, is there a simple example? maybe with my code. What exactly can I do with `ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]`? Or any other example

Comment: Please read [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact). The documentation is pretty clear about the difference.

Comment: @DavidMaze the more complex option would just be `--entrypoint 'sh'` :) This is probably a case where I would use the entrypoint but you are right, it could be clearer dependingly on how you run it.